# Need to decide which structure variant to use during startup in C

Tags: c

I need two different forms of a structure depending on the number of CPUs and memory

First struct:

```c
struct __my_struct{

    int a;
    long b;
    char c;

};
```

Second struct:

```c
struct __my_struct{

    int a;
    char c;

};
```

How can it be possible in C? When the process comes up it decides about one form and use it across the program.

Comment: Use a tagged `union`?

Comment: Maybe use a preprocessor directive?

Comment: Do you mean during runtime or compile time?

Comment: Identifiers that begin with a double underscore are reserved identifiers per [**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3):  "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Answer (score 1):

This task can be achieved both by using *macroconditioning* (so that the distinction will be done at compile time) or at runtime, using *unions*.
Usually the first solutions is used for programs (especially *embedded* programs) in which the system configuration is known at compilation time.

---

### Preprocessor solution

The use of processor directives makes possible, depending on compliation global defines (that are present **for sure** in a system with specific memory and CPU configurations) a structure definition is compiled istead the other one:

```
#if defined(A_SPECIFIC_CPU_AND_MEMORY_CONFIGURATION)
struct __my_struct{
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
};
#else
struct __my_struct{
    int a;
    char c;
};
#endif
```

In this way, what you need is just understanding what is your `A_SPECIFIC_CPU_AND_MEMORY_CONFIGURATION` value.

Your actual configuration will be more likely a combination between two *defines* (either with `#define` directive or with `-D` compiler option):

```
#define MY_MEM_SIZE_MB 8
#define MY_CPU CPU_XYZ
```

so, in a more realistic scenario, you'll have to do something like this:

```
#if defined(CPU_XYZ) && (MY_MEM_SIZE_MB == 8)

  // Define a struct

#elif defined(CPU_XYZ) && (MY_MEM_SIZE_MB == 4)

  // define another struct

// add how many #elifs as required

#else

  // define default struct

#endif
```

You will be able to access your struct all over your code. You'll just have to use the same *macroconditioning* in order to be sure to use the fields that are not common between the variants of the structs only when they are actually defined (in our example the `long b;` field).

---

### Runtime solution

We can do something also in case we want to take this decision at runtime. **But we have to accept some modifications in the code as well**.

The strategy is based on `union`s, special C data types C that allow to store different data types in the same memory location.

Each of your struct variants becomes is renamed so that it refers to the specific configuration:

```
struct __my_struct_configA
{
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
};

struct __my_struct_configB
{
    int a;
    char c;
};
```

Now, what we do is defining an `union`, containing struct variants defined above:

```
union __my_container {
    __my_struct_configA a;
    __my_struct_configB b;
}
```

How to access the elements of the single struct? We will have for sure a variable (it could be an `enum`) defining the current HW configuration. By testing it we can understand what struct is suitable for the current system, and what fields can be accessed:

```
typedef enum {
  HW_CONFIG_A,
  HW_CONFIG_B,
  /* ... */
} HWConfig_e;

void myFunc( HWConfig_e cfg, union __my_container *cont )
{
    switch( cfg )
    {
        case HW_CONFIG_A:
        {
             __my_struct_configA *cfgA = &(cont->a);

             printf("a=%d b=%l c=%c\n", cfgA->a, cfgA->b, cfgA->c );
             break;

        case HW_CONFIG_B:
        {
             __my_struct_configB *cfgB = &(cont->b);

             printf("a=%d (b=N/A) c=%c\n", cfgB->a, cfgB->c );
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is about deciding this at runtime.

Comment: @TanveerBadar please, tell me where the word "runtime" is present in the question. Anyway, later I'll check it again and I'll delete the answer if there's no way to fix it. ;)

Comment: @TanveerBadar I've updated my answer in order to provide guidance for both preprocessor and runtime soultions. Please consider retracting your downvote (even if I admit there's room for further revisions and improvements).

Comment: The `union` approach unfortunately means that your object always needs the larger amount of memory.  One possible reason for wanting to use the smaller struct when possible is to save memory, and using a union defeats that purpose.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree with you, and that's why I would opt to the macroconditioning option. Chosing the runtime option, IMHO, implies that the user has no strict memory issues, otherwise the other option would have been chosen. I surrender in judging the reasons behind this question... I suppose it is a matter of code style (or, maybe, the need to minimize the effort for a porting).

Answer (score 1):

You can have all code that works with the structs go through pointers, which can be of type `void *` in code that doesn't need to know which is being used.

```
struct data_v1 {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
};

struct data_v2 {
    int a;
    char c;
};

int data_version; // set to either 1 or 2 at startup

struct big {
    // lots of members
    void *the_data; // points to either data_v1 or data_v2
};

void *alloc_data(void) {
    if (data_version == 1) {
        struct data_v1 *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        p->a = 17;
        p->b = -9;
        p->c = 'x';
        return p;
    } else if (data_version == 2) {
        struct data_v2 *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        p->a = 14;
        p->c = 'y';
        return p;
    } else
        abort();
}

long get_b(void *data) {
    if (data_version == 1) {
        return ((struct data_v1 *)data)->b;
    }
    else if (data_version == 2) {
        return -42;  // default value
    }
    else
        abort();
}

void other_code(void) {
    // ....
    struct big s;
    s.the_data = alloc_data();
    //
    printf("%d\n", get_b(s.the_data));
    // ...
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/hkJZrm)

One advantage over the `union` approach is that you only allocate as much memory as is needed for the particular version of the struct being used.  There is malloc overhead, of course, so this might only be helpful  if one version of the struct is much larger than the other, or if you have large arrays of them.

This does mean that every piece of code that deals with the actual members of the `data_*` structs needs to be written in two cases like this, so you'll want to try to factor out all such code into particular functions (or, if necessary, macros).

This approach is a common way to achieve "runtime polymorphism" in C.  As you can see, it is much more awkward than in something like C++ where polymorphism is actually a language feature.  So a more drastic solution to this problem would be to switch your project to C++, where this is easily solved using derived classes.

Comment: `switch(data_version)`?

Comment: Nice answer. Let's say `union` solution has the advantage to not require mallocs, like in this case, so it is suitable for systems so basic that they don't have an heap area. (but in this case, like nearly in every embedded system, the preprocessor approach would be preferable).